# Is there a way to save youtube buffer before close browser to reopen it later

Tags: youtube, buffer

Is there some plugin or other software to save the downloaded video buffer to reopen the same buffer downloaded later?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this addon](http://lifehacker.com/preload-entire-youtube-videos-by-disabling-dash-playbac-1186454034) to make the video load completely (instead of loading as you go), then [NirSoft VideoCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html) to copy the downloaded video and then you can play it on vlc (or whatever video player you use).